# PostValidate datatable list values

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a list of items that are being displayed using a h:datatable like so:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.instructorsList}" var="ins">
    <p:column headerText="Name">
        <h:inputText value="#{ins.name}"/>                                   
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My spec is that I cannot allow a instructor to have the same name as another insturctor. So I need to have access to all the entire instructorList when it is submitted. I have attempted to validate using a postValidate f:event however due to the JSF lifecycle it does not update the model values till after the postValidation phase.

My attempt

```
<f:event listener="#{myBean.myMethod}" type="postValidate" />
```

Backing code

```
private List<instructors> instructorsList;

public void myMethod(ComponentSystemEvent event) {

  // Attempting to use the instructorsList with new values. However, this 
  // is at the wrong stage
}
```

How would I write a validator to accomplish checking for duplicate instructor names?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Do you have a problem with accessing the submitted name from withing the postValidate event listener? Or do you have a problem with setting the validation status within the listener?

Comment: Yes, I have a issue accessing the submit names from the postValidate event listener. The values have yet to be updated in my viewScoped bean.

Comment: postValidate is probably too late to affect the request processing. How exactly are you trying to access the submitted value currently?

Comment: Updated, you can see that this will not work with the JSF lifecycle. I have read I could possibly iterate through the list, but I am unsure how to do this using the ComponentSystemEvent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a listener, use the `getSubmittedValue` method on `HtmlInputText` to pull the value straight off the component. Also, `postValidate` is semantically late to call problems on the validation process. Use the `preValidate` method instead. Altogether, you should have

```
    public void myMethod(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
         HtmlInputText txtBox = (HtmlInputText)event.getComponent();
         String theValue = txtBox.getSubmittedValue().toString(); //the value in the textbox

         //based on the outcome of your validation, you also want to do the following

         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().setValidationFailed(); //flag the entire request as failing validation
         txtBox.setValid(false); //mark the component as failing validation

    }
```

**EDIT:** This approach is heavily hinged on the premise that your users will be submitting only one row at a time. In the case where the entire table/column is being submitted in one request, you'll find that evaluating each input field on by one doesn't do much to prevent race conditions; you should be looking toward cross-field validation instead.

**EDIT 2:** I was mistaken, you cannot have race conditions when the event listener is being called. The listener is executed for each row, sequentially. This allows you to safely check each row (perhaps against a `Map`, for duplicates), without worrying about race conditions.

Comment: good response, how would I do the cross-field validation? That is what I am really looking for how to do. I do not need to check fields on a individual basis

Comment: This would satisfy my requirements as I could use Map as a validation point, then maintain the count of how many fields have been validated. If I reach the end and the condition has not been satisfied I could invalidate the last field (or throw a validation error) to halt the lifecycle.